# XML pivot using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, pivot

I have the following XML format that I receive:
    -

```
<Origin>
  <PackageReferenceNumber>
     <Code>0</Code>
     <Value>QAST ROW PKG 01</Value>
  </PackageReferenceNumber>
  <PackageReferenceNumber>
    <Code>33</Code>
    <Value>12345</Value>
  </PackageReferenceNumber>
</Origin>
```

I would like to have it formatted:

```
<Origin>
  <PackageReferenceNumber>
    <Code1>0</Code1>
    <Value1>QAST ROW PKG 01</Value1>
    <Code2>33</Code2>
    <Value2>12345</Value2>
  </PackageReferenceNumber>
</Origin>
```

I am using XSLT to transform the XML.  Below is the XSLT code that I am currently using to transform the XML.  I am new to XML and XSLT.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="var1_initial" select="."/>
    <QuantumViewResponse>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">file:///C:/Users/test.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <QuantumViewEvents>
            <SubscriptionEvents>
                <SubscriptionFile>
                    <Origin>
                        <xsl:for-each select="QuantumViewResponse/QuantumViewEvents/SubscriptionEvents/SubscriptionFile/Origin/PackageReferenceNumber">
                            <xsl:variable name="var3_current" select="."/>
                            <PackageReferenceNumber>
                                <Code>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="floor(Code)"/>
                                </Code>
                                <Value>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                                </Value>
                            </PackageReferenceNumber>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="QuantumViewResponse/QuantumViewEvents/SubscriptionEvents/SubscriptionFile/Origin">
                            <xsl:variable name="var4_current" select="."/>
                            <TrackingNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="TrackingNumber"/>
                            </TrackingNumber>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Origin>
                </SubscriptionFile>
            </SubscriptionEvents>
        </QuantumViewEvents>
    </QuantumViewResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to change the format in such a way. The input XML is much easier to work with!

Still, from the looks of your current XSLT, it seems like you have only shown a portion of your XML. In which case it may be best to start with the Identity Template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then add a template to match the `Origin` in which you create a single `PackageReferenceNumber` and then select all the existing ones.

```
<xsl:template match="Origin">
  <xsl:copy>
    <PackageReferenceNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PackageReferenceNumber" />
    </PackageReferenceNumber>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And in the template that matched `PackageReferenceNumber` you would get the current position, and then after selecting all its child nodes, you would use the position to change their names:

```
<xsl:template match="PackageReferenceNumber">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{$pos}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />     

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="Origin">
    <xsl:copy>
      <PackageReferenceNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PackageReferenceNumber" />
      </PackageReferenceNumber>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PackageReferenceNumber">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{$pos}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, a preferred way to do this would be have a ref to the package as an attribute instead. Try replace the last template with this instead:

```
  <xsl:template match="PackageReferenceNumber">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="ref" select="$pos" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

This produces the following output

```
<Origin>
   <PackageReferenceNumber>
      <Code ref="1">0</Code>
      <Value ref="1">QAST ROW PKG 01</Value>
      <Code ref="2">33</Code>
      <Value ref="2">12345</Value>
   </PackageReferenceNumber>
</Origin>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I am new to XML.  This is a part of an SSIS package that is populating a table in a SQL database.  The reason I am trying to parse it this way is because each "PackageReferenceNumber"  in the XML file needs to be inserted into one row but separate columns in the table.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could use an attribute to record the number, rather than amend the child element name. I've made an edit to my answer to show this.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I was also able to grab a few additional pieces from the XML file that I needed. I appreciate your help!